# Print value in multidimensional array with specific value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
$sim = array( 
    array( 
        word => "happy", 
        percent => 100,
    ),
);
```

And I want to search the word with highest percent in my array.

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

```
$max = -9999999; //will hold max val
$found_item = null; //will hold item with max val;
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    if($v['Total']>$max)
    {
        $max = $v['Total'];
        $found_item = $v;
    }
}
echo "max value is $max";
print_r($found_item);
```

[Working demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k2b-6xp)